# I trying to add below script for list some products while adding this script menu bar is not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

Please explain?menu bar it is not working.the below code for listing some element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('li a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
if(ullist.is(':visible')){
ullist.hide('slow');
} else {
ullist.show('slow');
}
});
});
//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/): *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element* - Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function does not refer to the loaded event. Standard jQuery practice is to use the [document.ready event](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() ...
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
        if (ullist.is(':visible')) {
            ullist.hide('slow');
        } else {
            ullist.show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```